# Receiving error "The getter 'fname' isn't defined for the type 'List<ModelUserGroup>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and trying to understand the below.
The following is the controller that handles the data received from a mysql DB. The `ModelSamejt` model represents the groups and the `ModelUserGroup` represents the users in each group.

```
Future<List<ModelSamejt>> getSamejts(List<ModelSamejt> q) async {
  var request = await Dio().get(Api.baseUrl + Api.api + Api.samejt);
  print("${Api.baseUrl + Api.api + Api.samejt}");
  for (Map<String, dynamic> samejt in request.data) {
    List<ModelUserGroup> mqc = [];
    for (Map<String, dynamic> content in samejt['content']) {
      mqc.add(ModelUserGroup(  // represents the users in each group
          uid: content['uid'],
          puid: content['puid'],
          avatar: content['avatar'],
          fname: content['fname'],
          lname: content['lname'],
          xp: content['xp'],


      ));
    }
    q.add(ModelSamejt(    // represents the groups
        pid: samejt['pid'],
        grp: samejt['grp'],
        country: samejt['country'],
        indust: samejt['indust'],
        job: samejt['job'],
        content: mqc));
  }
  return q;
}
```

In the view, I'm able to display the `group` fields successfully using something like this:

```
Text(
  '${listSamejt[index].grp}',
  style: TextStyle( color: Colors.black,fontSize: 15),
),
```

My question is how to display the 'users' fields related to the group.

I tried the `'${listSamejt[index].content.fname}'` but received this error although `fname` is defined in the model :

```
The getter 'fname' isn't defined for the type 'List<ModelUserGroup>'.
```

Please let me know if any additional code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, `listSamejt[index].content` is a List and you are getting the error because you are trying to access `fname` of List class. This will throw the error you are seeing.

To do this, you will have to loop through `listSamejt[index].content`. Something like this

```
listSamejt.forEach(sameJt=>{
  // sameJt = ModelSamejt
  sameJt.content.forEach(item=>{
    // item = ModelUserGroup
    // item.fname - this should work
    print(item)
  })
})
```

Edit: You should probably modify `getSamejts` to look something like this:

```
Future<List<ModelSamejt>> getSamejts() async {
  List<ModelSamejt> q =[]; // <<===

  var request = await Dio().get(Api.baseUrl + Api.api + Api.samejt);
  
  // ... other code here
}
```

Comment: Foreach is giving this error : This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: @AbdallahSakre and I'm assuming that you are initialising the value of `listSamejt` with the return value of `getSamejts` right? Something like 
`final listSamejt = await this.getSamejts()` ??

Comment: In the view, I added :  Text(
                                            listSamejt.forEach(sameJt=>{
                                            sameJt.content.forEach(item=>{
                                            print(item)
                                            })
                                            })
                                        ),

Comment: I'm initializing like this: Future<List<ModelSamejt>>? getSamejt;
  List<ModelSamejt> listSamejt = []; void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSamejt = getSamejts(listSamejt);
  }